# IBM RFT does not find .net object from framework

Tags: rft

I have to check a frame window with RFT which is written with a .net framework. My problem is, after adding the frame as Testobject via drag and drop to the script it works fine. But after restarting RFT, it isnt able to recognize that frame any more, neither with find method or the highlight function for objects.

I read that there is a way to add objects to the proxys. But this frame is declared at proxy .Net.FormProxy and this proxy is existing in the file rational_ft.rftcust as

```
<Obj L=".Proxy">
<ClassName>Rational.Test.Ft.Domain.Net.FormProxy</ClassName>
<Replaces/>
<UsedBy>[System.Windows.Forms]System.Windows.Forms.Form</UsedBy>
</Obj>
```

I dont get what is the problem. Especially, why is it working some times but not always.

Thx for help..

Comment: Is restarting RFT the problem or do you restart your application under test (AUT) too? Often when there is a problem with object recognition after restarting the AUT, some property is used for object recognition which changes after every restart. What are the recognition properties used for your frame?

Comment: Thx for that tip. But I have 4 properties and they have always the same valuese. I observe the same effect as described above when I search for this object only with the .class property like rootTestObject.find(atDescendant(... . I m wondering if it is a bug in RFT.

Comment: No idea what might be the problem then. Anyhow, it sounds quite strange—might be it's a bug...

Comment: Yes, looks like :(. Maybe I write a ticket to IBM. Thanks your for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have mentioned may happen for the following reasons.

The object recognition is indeed changing . And it is not necessarily the object that you are having problem with has object recognition issue , but an object  in the parent heirarchy  of this object (unless this object is the top level object).

The second reason could be the application is not getting enabled during playback time and you can try  getRootTestObject().enableForTesting(/)  API to force enable the application.

On a recorded  Form object  in the Object Map  try to use the  "update recognition properties"  to see if there is change in recognition properties in actual vs recorded object.

You can also just test a different simple Form Application to see if the issue  is related to your application  or if it is general issue in your environment( I suspect it to be related to the application).